# How to add additional libraries in ExecuteStreamCommand in Nifi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I'm not able to run a Python script from ExecuteStreamCommand.

These are the processor properties:
Command arguments: /home/directory/test.py
Command path: /bin/python3
Working directory: /home/directory

Error message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/test.py", line 1, in  import nipyapi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nipyapi'

Comment: Please check if the `nipapi` module is installed in your current python PIP. You can check it by executing `$ pip list` command. It's more convenient to install and use a [python virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), and after enabling the venv, you can [install your pip modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), and then execute your scripts.

Comment: If you are using NiFi cluster, then you need to install `nipapi` module on all the NiFi nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I am able to get ExecuteStreamCommand processor to run python scripts with imported modules is to install the imported modules on the actual machine itself. Therefore, this means running pip or pip3 install {insert module name} on the command prompt for each system that this processor is running on.

Comment: I have all the modules installed in my machine, and I can run the script in the command line. I'm running nifi locally so I don't know what else I could be missing.

Comment: A few options include verifying that the module is properly installed and running the program from the command line and if there is not the same issue with the library, then the library would be installed.

Comment: Reinstalled nipyapi with sudo permissions and it worked, i wasn't properly installed then.

Comment: Glad it worked and that I could be of assistance! Please feel free to accept this answer if I helped solved the issue.